# Persistent Internet Explorer mode under Edge without GPO

Tags: java, applet, microsoft-edge

we need to start an older java applet via Edge with IE Mode. The 30 (to 90) days solution works, but none of the official or inofficial solutions for a permanent solution.

**The temporary solution:**

Under edge://settings/defaultBrowser loading pages in the Internet Explorer Mode needs to be allowed. If the adress (http://localhost/startpage.html) is put there, it will open in IE Mode for 30 days (or up to 90). But we need to have it permanent since we can't manually add them there every 90 days for every customer.

**This was tried so far:**

1. Using the --ie-mode-test parameter by running edge with the following shortcut: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" http://localhost/startpage.html --ie-mode-test

Doesn't work anymore, the parameter was officially discontinued. Source: https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#15453

2. Using the Site List Manager via edge://compat/SiteListManager . Putting the site there manually didn't result in opening in IE Mode. This was it's content:

```
<site-list version="1">
  <site url="http://localhost/startpage.html">
    <compat-mode>Default</compat-mode>
    <open-in>IE11</open-in>
  </site>
</site-list>
```

3. Creating an XML file via Enterprise Mode Site List Manager and importing it in Edge. It was a little bit different than the XML created by Edge, but it didn't work either. This was it's content:

```
<site-list version="1">
  <created-by>
    <tool>EMIESiteListManager</tool>
    <version>12.0.0.0</version>
    <date-created>04/22/2022 10:31:03</date-created>
  </created-by>
  <site url="localhost/frischli/lager.html">
    <compat-mode>Default</compat-mode>
    <open-in>IE11</open-in>
  </site>
</site-list>
```

**There is another small thing:** On every Microsoft page, there is a reference to the GPOs of Edge being in the following path: Computer/User -> administrative templates -> Edge, but that doesn't exist for me. The Edge policies are under Computer/User -> administrative templates -> Microsoft Components -> Microsoft Edge.

Does anybody know how to get this running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The IE mode site list setting in the browser only keep 30-90 days, so if you need to make it work in IE mode for a long time, you need to configure it via group policy.

> Creating an XML file via Enterprise Mode Site List Manager and importing it in Edge. It was a little bit different than the XML created by Edge, but it didn't work either.

The configuration file format generated by this tool is more in line with the specification. The reason why this configuration does not work is related to your second question. You can refer to this document to view the format requirements of this configuration file：[Enterprise Mode schema v.2 guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/enterprise-mode-schema-version-2-guidance).

> On every Microsoft page, there is a reference to the GPOs of Edge being in    the following path: Computer/User -> administrative templates -> Edge, but            that doesn't exist for me.

First you need to download and install the Edge policy template, please navigate to [offical link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business/download) and select your environment, and then download the policy template like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DatzI.png). And then install it in your machine, finally configure Edge IE mode policy.

For the installation of Edge policy templates and the configuration of Edge IE mode, you can refer to these two documents:

[Configure Microsoft Edge policy settings on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/configure-microsoft-edge).
[Configure IE mode policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-internet-explorer-integration).

Finally after your configuration is complete, you can navigate to `edge://compat/enterprise` in Edge and click the `Force update` button to see if it takes effect, by default, group policy will take a minute to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the [CheerpJ Applet Runner](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/cheerpj-applet-runner/ebfcpaoldmijengghefpohddmfpndmic) extension, developed by Leaning Technologies.

Full disclosure, I am CTO of Leaning Technologies and lead dev of CheerpJ

Please note that the extension if free *only* for personal use, any commercial or business use requires a license. Please see [here](https://leaningtech.com/cheerpj-applet-runner/) for more info.